# accessType missing in passport.authenticate

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I am using `passport-google-oauth` and I need to get the refreshToken. It normally returns `undefined`.

```js
app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    scope: [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
    ],
    prompt: "consent",
  })
);
```

I've browsed the internet, and there were old solutions of adding `accessType: "offline"`. But it seems like in this version of `passport` there is no `accessType`. What do?

Answer (score 0):

Just add `accessType: 'offline'` inside the authenticate function input object.

```
app.get('/auth/google', 
  passport.authenticate('google', {
    scope : ['profile', 'email'],
    accessType: 'offline'
  })
);
```